# How to rotate background images every 5 seconds? javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, background

I'm not sure how to explain this properly, so bear with me...

I've been searching for an answer on how to rotate through my images/background folder so that it changes my background every 5 seconds, also it would be a bonus if it could fade in and out as well. I found a few similar answers but am experiencing some difficulty trying to adapt it to my page.

I'm not sure what information I should be providing, so I'm just going to go ahead and post my index first followed by my style sheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link href="css/styler.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<!--Start Main Canvas-->
<div class="maincanvas">



</div><!--End Main Canvas-->
</body>
</html>
```

I'm currently displaying my background in my "styler.css" style sheet as follows

```
 .maincanvas {
    background-image: url(../images/background/bg_image01.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

I hope that's enough information, any help with this would be fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: malware @KundanSinghChouhan

Answer (score 1):

You could use css keyframes to do such a thing.

So you would set the keyframes, you would need to browser prefix these, a quick way would be to use http://prefixr.com .

```
@keyframes "bg" {
 0% {
    background: url(link/to/image);
 }
 20% {
    background: url(link/to/image);
 }
 40% {
    background: url(link/to/image);
 }
 60% {
    background: url(link/to/image);
 }
 80% {
    background: url(link/to/image);
 }
 100% {
    background: url(link/to/image);
 }

}
```

Then set up the animation (again remember to prefix) something like this.

```
animation: bg 25s 0 infinite ease;
```

So 5 x 5s = 25s total animation time on an infinite loop.

Of course the downside to this is that you would have to manually add the image urls.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://trendmedia.com/news/infinite-rotating-images-using-jquery-javascript/) is an example of rotating images, but it uses jQuery.

Comment: This isn't an answer, put some love in it.